Algorithm for building the optimal railway
I got the following task at the university.
Task
There are several data blocks:

Data: It stores the types of rails, the cost, and the number of rails of the type Rail Type at a given cost.
Rail types:
{
L1, L2, L3, L4 // straight lengths 1-4
T4, T8 // turns at an angle pi/4, pi/8
B1 // bridge, used to build a road over another road
}
Route: It stores the coordinates of points on the plane and the cost of these points.

After the road is built, the profit of the road is calculated the following way.
The cost of each point of the road is calculated:  v_i / (1 + d_ij), where d_ij is the minimum distance from the junction points of the path elements to v_i.
The final profit is calculated as: F = Points_sum - Road_cost.
It is necessary to build the most profitable road.
Example input
DATA
L1 42 47
L2 35 41
L3 30 5
L4 19 19
T4 23 45
T8 6 6
B1 2 28
/
ROUTE
0 0 61
10.3 1.0 -17.7
/
ORDER
L1 1
T4 1
T4 1
L1 1
T4 1
T4 1
L1 1
T4 1
T4 1
L1 1
T4 1
T4 1
/

Input description
DATA Block:
This defines the rail types, their costs, and the quantity available for building.
Here:
L1 represents a straight rail of length 1 with a cost of 42, and 47 pieces are available.
T4 represents a turn rail with an angle of π/4, costing 23, with 45 pieces available.
Other rail types (L2, L3, etc.) follow the same logic.
ROUTE Block:
This defines points on the plane with a corresponding value (or "cost of the point").
Example: 0 0 61
Here:
The point (0, 0) has a value of 61.
Also the point (10.3, 1.0) has a value of -17.7
ORDER Block:
This defines the sequence of rails to be used in building the road.
The order of these rails specifies how the road is constructed.
Example: L1 1 T4 1 T4 1 L1 1 T4 1 T4 1 L1 1 T4 1 T4 1 L1 1 T4 1 T4 1
Here:
L1 1 means a straight rail of length 1 is used.
T4 1 means a turn rail of angle π/4 is used.
My ideas

The usual brute force (would be useful for checking the solution)
I thought to train the RL model, since the formulation is very similar to the RL problem
I was thinking of using Ordered Upwind Methods (link below). It seemed that the production sounded similar, but I did not figure out how to use it.
https://math.berkeley.edu/~sethian/2006/Explanations/ordered_upwind_explain.html


This post expresses ideas, but there is no question.

Yes, I'm sorry, I forgot to finish it.
Question: what algorithms can I try to use to solve this problem?

This is likely off topic here. Asking for a list of things is too broad. Asking for one algorithm is like asking for some suggestion. Both are closure reasons. However, if you have attempted something, and bumped into a problem you could not resolve, you can ask about that specific issue.

This strikes me as more of an optimisation problem than an exact algorithm problem especially since directions are limited and bridges exist, so the road sections interact. You could look into machine learning solutions but I doubt there's a SO question to be found here.

Please clarify the "order block"  This seems to be an input.  Perhaps it is a list of available rails which can be selected from?  But you already have that in the data block, I think.  So maybe it is actually belongs in the output, showing the rail actually used?

There are a lot of details to be implemented in this question, but the heart of the problem is to find an optimum set of "roads" that link all the points.
This is the minimum spanning tree ( MST ) problem.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree
You will need to construct a graph that connects every point to every other point, then weight each link by an estimate of the cost to build that link. You can start by estimating the weight by the Pythagorean distance between each point pair. Use any graph theory library to find the MST.
Build your railway on the route suggested by the MST.
Update the cost estimate of each link used with the actual cost calculated with all the details.
Re-run the MST method on the updated cost graph.  If the MST is significantly changed, then repeat until the changes becomes insignificant.
Hopefully, this will converge quickly on a solution that is optimal or close to it.
========================
Alternative Algorithm for cases with hundreds of points or more:
Use a clustering algorithm ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis ) to identify clusters in the points ( I usually find K-means to be adequate and very simple to implement ).
In each cluster build a hub and spoke railway.  Use the MST algorithm above to link the cluster hubs.
